# Linq query to get all items with an average rating score

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have an **event** entity with relation to 1+ **rating** entities. I need to query my database to get only events with (for example) an average of 2 stars rating on the total of ratings of this specific event. Rate1, 2, 3, 4 can have values between [0,1,2,3,4,5] stars.

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Rate1 { get; set; }
    public int Rate2 { get; set; }
    public int Rate3 { get; set; }
    public int Rate4 { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

As an example: 1 event with 3 ratings related like this:

Id: 1
Rate1: **3**
Rate2: **2**
Rate3: **5**
Rate4: **1**

Id: 2
Rate1: **4**
Rate2: **1**
Rate3: **0**
Rate4: **1**

Id: 3
Rate1: **3**
Rate2: **1**
Rate3: **3**
Rate4: **2**

The average value is calculated as follow: ( (3+2+5+1) + (4+1+0+1) + (3+1+3+2) ) / 12 = 2,16 (rounded to 2)

I am wondering if this is possible to write a Linq query to get all the events which are rated 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, technically.

```
var eventsWithRatingOfExactlyTwo = Events
    .Where(e => (e.Ratings.Average(r => r.Rate1 + r.Rate2 + r.Rate3 + r.Rate4) / 4) == 2);
```

I doubt the utility of looking for an exact rating, though: you'll probably want to look for items where the rating is in a given range instead.

I'd encourage you to re-think your domain model, too. What makes those four "Rate"s so special that you're unlikely to ever add another Rate per rating? Those should probably be represented as rows in another table, rather than columns on this table.

Comment: Each rating (1, 2, 3, 4) are for different aspects (ex: Rate1 for 'Global experience', Rate2 for 'Facilities', ...). The code you posted here helped me a lot. I simply surrounded with Math.Round( ...Average..., 0)